# How to check for administrator privelege in remote CimSession

Tags: powershell, remote-access

Using a CimSession created with

```
New-CimSession -ComputerName $computeraddress -Credential $credential
```

I need to be able to tell if the credentials I used give me administrator privilege on the remote computer.
On a local computer or using PSremoting I can check using [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/95431/in-a-powershell-script-how-can-i-check-if-im-running-with-administrator-privil).
Is there a way to check this using the Cim cmdlets with a CimSession?

I am aware that in most cases the credentials need to be of an administrator account to even establish the CimSession, however I would like to check this explicitly.

Comment: CimCession will give you access to WMI, so if the user is explicitly in the 'administrators' group, you can use the information provided there to [list administrators members](https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/wmi/2338/query-local-administrators-with-wmi/), but if the user in a nested group member of the local administrators group this may be harder. A PSSession will be more reliable to check this information with the answer you found. And in the PSSession you can use CIM cmdlets but remotely on the local computer inside the PSSession.

Comment: @Hazrelle I'm specifically asking for a CimSession solution as I'm constrained to use DCOM protocol and PS 3.0 compatible commands. Because of that PSSession is not an option. Comparing to the list of administrator members is the closest to an answer I've seen, but I hope to get something more direct.

Comment: What problem are you solving? (Why not just try what you need to do?)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart There is potentially a large amount of different operations that happen afterwards and it is cleaner to check all the pre-requisites beforehand. If I don't find a way to do this efficiently, then yes, just attempting the operations is the next step. If you know some low-cost Cim operation that would reliably fail without administrator privileges I could potentially use that for the check.